# Smooth a positive function on a smooth manifold

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:M\to\Bbb R$ be a positive function on a smooth manifold $M$ such that there is no convergent sequence of points $x_k\in M$ such that $f(x_k)\to 0$. Is there a smooth (or at least continuous) function $g:M\to\Bbb R$ such that $0<g(x)<f(x)$ for any $x\in M$?

Comment: Why "complex analysis"? And another thing: is $M$ compact?

Comment: I should have tagged only "analysis"! If $M$ is compact, it is easy.

Comment: I removed "complex analysis" for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First claim, that you seem to know: for all compact $K\subset M$, there exists $c>0$ such that $f(x) > c$ on $K$, for the opposite would imply the existence of a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ such that $f(x_n)<1/n$, and extracting a convergent subsequence would contradict your hypothesis.

Second claim, which is a basic property of differentiable manifold: there exists a locally finite covering of open sets $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ such that the closure of $U_\alpha$ is compact. Indeed differentiable manifolds are metrizable and so [paracompact](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-020-02/S0002-9939-1969-0236876-3/S0002-9939-1969-0236876-3.pdf), which means that every open cover has an locally finite refinement. Then, choosing for each $x\in M$ a neighborhood $U_x$ such that the closure of $U_x$ is compact, a locally finite refinement of the covering $(U_x)_{x\in M}$ satisfies the claim.

Finally, you can choose a smooth partition of unity $(\chi_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ subordinate to this open cover. According to the first claim, there exists a family of positive real numbers $(c_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ such that on $U_\alpha$, $f(x)>c_\alpha>0$, and you can choose $g(x)=\sum_{\alpha} c_\alpha\chi_\alpha(x)$.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. @Dino : this answer deserves upvote and accept, unless you are not convinced.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sorry, I'm newbie here, I did not know that I needed to accept it.